# Adjektivdeklination typ 2

Tags: adjective

I'm learning about the different adjektivdeklination, and I tried to come up with my own sentence, using adjectives.

> Meine hübsch Mädchen besucht kein klein Museum.

By my understanding, there should **not** be an added ending on hübsch neither on klein, since I have choosen to use mein and kein.

I have the following table (see below), but after reading on https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/adjektive/deklination
it seems that I may have misinterpreted my own table.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you have misinterpreted your table, or it is wrong. Also, *Mädchen* is neuter.

Comment: "Mein hübsches Mädchen besucht kein  kleines Museum"? @carstens

Comment: Yes, even though that is a strange thing to say ;)

Comment: @CarstenS Wow? Why? It looks to me exactly like a tricky example sentence from a German school textbook. :-)

Comment: Willst Du sagen, dass es nur große Museen besucht; nur kleine Ausstellungen, aber nicht Museen oder ein bestimmes, kleines Museum nicht besucht? *Kein kleines Museeum* lässt das alles offen.

Comment: And "mein hübsches Mädchen" is also slightly creepy.

Comment: I interpret "Mein hübsches Mädchen" as, my beutiful girl, why do you think that is creepy? Have I misinterpreted the meaning, or is it something like some social norm? @carstens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following jpg will help. I did it myself, you may use it as you like.
[image: Übersicht über die Deklination von Adjektiven]

Answer (score 0):

### BASICS

Which adjective-ending you use depends on whether or not you find an article-ending **in front of the adjective**.

E.g. in the sentence:

- Ich sehe ein**en** grünen Frosch.

you find "ein**en**" with the ending "-en" in front of grünen.

In the sentences:

- Ich sehe **[X]** ein grünes Auto.
- Ich sehe **[X]** grüne Autos.

you don't find any article-endings [indicated by the **X**]

NEXT STEPS

Once you have figured out whether or not there's an article-ending in front of the adjective, you "only" need to apply the following rules:

---

### **IN CASE OF AN ENDING**

SIMPLY APPLY THE FOLLOWING RULES:

1. Once -en always -en
2. Adjectives in Plural Dative or Genitive always -en
3. After der / das / die always -e

EXAMPLES FOR EACH RULE:

1. Ich sehe ein**en** grün**en** Frosch [ein**en** ends in -**en** so grün**en** has to end in -**en** as well.]
2. Plural:   Ich sehe die grün**en** Frösche.

   Dativ:    Ich helfe dem grün**en** Frosch.

   Genitiv:  Ich esse die Beine des grün**en** Frosches.
3. (der = masculine): Der grün**e** Frosch ist lecker (+).

   (das = neuter):    Das grün**e** Auto ist schnell (+).

   (die = feminine):  Die grün**e** Blume ist schön (+).

*(+) Adjectives at the end of a sentence never get any ending.*

---

### IN CASE THERE'S **NO ARTICLE ENDING**

"simply" add the ending that a regular article would take if it was in the adjectives place. A couple of examples:

- Ich sehe [X] grün**e** Autos. <-- **grün** gets the same ending as a "di**e**" would get in its place
- Ich habe ein grün**es** Auto. <-- **grün** gets the same ending as a "da**s**" would get in its place

---

This is just a rough overview of a really logical and beautiful technique which is much better explained and visualized [in a video I made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9eaPNVYm1A) for those interested.

Viel Erfolg mit Deinem Deutsch

Comment: On the Stackexchange Network self-promotion generally is frowned upon. This case is borderline as the video really is helpful, is explained here in detail and it was made clear that you are the author. I hope you understand that I had to edit out the promotional bit to make it less prominent.

Comment: For more also read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way

Comment: Dear @Takkat. The question is what you consider self-promotion:The video is free of charge and the best out there. Any former answer is simply way more complex and doesn't help the user as good as my answer. Now, I of course could ask a friend to post this under her name and you wouldn't consider it self-promotion. But I don't work like this. I offer solid advice to help the learner / user. What would your suggestion be here? That I ask others to share my expertise? It would also help me if I could see what you have taken out so that I can avoid such content in the future.

Comment: FYI: that exactly was why we did not remove this post. Your other post was already flagged as spam because the video you linked to had a promo for your book in it. More here: http://german.stackexchange.com/help/behavior and http://german.stackexchange.com/help/promotion. Because the SE network sadly is a highly frequented target for all kinds of spam there is little room for debate. All edits can be viewed by clicking on the [*edited xxx ago*](http://german.stackexchange.com/posts/34408/revisions) link.

Comment: A sidenote: *Now, I of course could ask a friend to post this under her name and you wouldn't consider it self-promotion.* – As your friend would advertise your content for their own good (to nurture your friendship), this would also be what we classify as spam – if they do not disclose their affiliation to you. In general, if your post (and not your link) actually answers the question, you disclose your affiliation, and you do not overdo it, everything should be okay.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Danke Dir.

Comment: @Takkat Danke Dir. Alles klar.